# Is there a way to edit InfoView settings programmatically?

Tags: enterprise-architect

Is there a way in Enterprise Architect to modify elements displayed in InfoView element display by the means of EA API?

Answer (score 2):

`InfoView` and its behavior is one of the undocumented features in EA API, so it may change without any notice. Following description is based on EA 13.5 build 1352.

The way it is implemented is somewhat weird (a good reason not to document it).
First, where the `InfoView` data is stored.
`InfoView` display mode is switched on by adding

```
OPTIONS_duid=InfoView=value:;
```

into field *styleex* of the table `t_diagram`, where **`duid`** is the short unique identifier of the diagram element (as in field `InstanceId` in `t_diagramobjects`) and **`value`** is a number, which bits are (MSB to LSB):

```
 x   x   x   x   x   x   x 

 |   |   |   |   |   |   |_   ICON

 |   |   |   |   |   |___   TYPE

 |   |   |   |   |_____   STEREOTYPE

 |   |   |   |_______   STATUS

 |   |   |_________   PHASE

 |   |___________  VERSION

 |_____________  AUTHOR
```

So the information about the element display format is stored in the diagram tables (and API object).
The `styleEx` field contains more than just this information; the information elements in the field are separated by semicolon (**;**) and their order is sometimes important, so don't touch the rest of this field, unless you know exactly know, what you're doing.

Let's assume we have diagram with `DiagramId=12345`, element with `ElementId=6789`.
So switching the `InfoView` ON and display the icon for the given element on our diagram shall be done like this (VbScript):

```
dim diag 'as EA.Diagram
dim el 'as EA.Element
dim dob 'as EA.DiagramObject
dim duid 'as String
set diag=Repository.getDiagramById(12345)
set el=Repository.getElementById(6789)

'find diagram object corresponding to the element in given diagram
for each dob in diag.DiagramObjects  
  if dob.ElementId=el.ElementId then
    duid=dob.InstanceId
  end if
next
' switch on the Infoview with an icon
diag.StyleEx=diag.StyleEx & "OPTIONS_" & duid & "=InfoView="1:;"
'save it
diag.Update
```

Notes:
You need to reload the diagram to see the changes.
Use `Repository.SqlQuery()` function to find the `DiagramObject` in production code; the example code is way too slow.
If the `InfoView` information element already exists in the `StyleEx` property of the diagram, you need to replace it instead of adding a new one.

Comment: Hey, cool. Would you mind adding that piece to my Inside book?